# How to add some spaces before z = 0;?

Tags: indentation

I'm trying to do a quick example with Pascal codes.

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\begin{document}
program first; \\ 
const\\  
z = 0;
\\
var\\
n,m: integer;\\
p,q: real\\
begin \\
end.
\end{document}
```

And I want to insert some spaces before `z = 0;` But `\(quad \) \=0;` does not work. What can I do for that?

Comment: You seem to be printing a source code of some program. Have you seen the package `listings`? It is there to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a quick solution needing no extra packages, just use the `verbatim` environment for program codes. It respects spaces and line breaks in the source.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
program first;  
const
  z = 0;

var
n,m: integer;
p,q: real
begin 
end.
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

For more sophisticated features, you could try the [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package, or the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. Don't forget that [Real Programmers Don't Use PASCAL](http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/real.programmers.html), though.

Comment: Yes. I hate Pascal, I just need it for a programming course.